# Facebook messenger bot app - persistent menu not appearing

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a Facebook chatbot app. I've set the persistent menu with some JSON using an HTTP POST and a valid page access token.

To check I set it correctly, I do a GET request to `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?fields=persistent_menu&access_token=TOKEN` with a working token.

The response I get is:

```
{u'data': [{u'persistent_menu': [{u'composer_input_disabled': False,
 u'locale': u'en_US'},
{u'call_to_actions': [{u'call_to_actions': [{u'payload': u'whatever',
     u'title': u'action1',
     u'type': u'postback'},
    {u'payload': u'whatever 2',
     u'title': u'action2',
     u'type': u'postback'}],
   u'title': u'my title',
   u'type': u'nested'},
  {u'title': u'my title URL',
   u'type': u'web_url',
   u'url': u'http://google.com/',
   u'webview_height_ratio': u'full'}],
 u'composer_input_disabled': False,
 u'locale': u'default'}]}]}
```

Which is what I put, so all good so far.

But when I open the Messenger app on iOS or visit `messenger.com` on Chrome desktop Mac OS X, I don't see any menu!

[image]

Curiously, on my server webhook endpoint I also DO receive the "Get Started" button press postback. So that is working.

My webhook to has permissions: `messages, messaging_postbacks, messaging_optins, message_deliveries, message_reads`.

I have tried:

- Refreshing on web
- Killing app on iOS and restarting it
- Deleting conversation and reloading bot
- Waiting 30 minutes and trying all of the above again

And none of those worked. I do still see a loading spinner in my Messenger iOS app - maybe Facebook's servers are just slow at updating my app? 30 minutes seems pretty extreme though.

Is there something wrong with my JSON for the persistent menu setup? That seems like the only thing that could be wrong.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I checked back, it has been more than 24 hours and still no menu is  appearing.

Comment: How did you solved the issue then?

Comment: It was a small bug in messenger. I brought it up to them messenger team and it is now patched!

Comment: Sorry, [it's still not fixed man](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46749142/2404470).

Answer (score 0):

Try do it using the Postman App and there use POST with these parameters:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=xxx

And fill the body with this:

```
{
  "setting_type": "call_to_actions",
  "thread_state": "existing_thread",
  "call_to_actions": [
       {"type": "web_url",
      "title": "test",
      "url": "https://test.com"
       },
    {
      "type": "postback",
      "title": "Help",
      "payload": "help"
    },
    {
      "type": "postback",
      "title": "Website",
      "payload": "web"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can read more about persistent menu in the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/persistent-menu

Answer (score 0):

You can form a request body given below:

```
{
"get_started":{
    "payload":"<GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD>"
},
"persistent_menu":[
{
  "locale":"default",
  "composer_input_disabled": true,
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "title":"Menu",
      "type":"nested",
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "title":"Pay Bill",
          "type":"postback",
          "payload":"PAYBILL_PAYLOAD"
        },
        {
          "title":"History",
          "type":"postback",
          "payload":"HISTORY_PAYLOAD"
        },
        {
          "title":"Contact Info",
          "type":"postback",
          "payload":"CONTACT_INFO_PAYLOAD"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type":"web_url",
      "title":"Latest News",
      "url":"http://www.messenger.com/",
      "webview_height_ratio":"full"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "locale":"zh_CN",
  "composer_input_disabled":true,
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "title":"Pay Bill",
      "type":"postback",
      "payload":"PAYBILL_PAYLOAD"
    }
  ]    
}
]
}
```

and the uri you can follow up is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```